# Weak formulation of Poisson equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am learning about partial differential equations and I would like clarification on the weak formulation of the following 1D poission equation.

Here is what I learned:

$-u_{xx} = f(x)$ in $\Omega = (0,1)$

$u(0)=u(1)=0$

, where $f\in C(\Omega) $

To derive a weak formulation, we first start with a classical solution $u(x) \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\overline\Omega)  $. Then, we take any $v(x) \in C^1(\Omega)$ with $v(0)=v(1)=0$, and by multiplying the both sides of the Poission equation by $v(x)$ and integrating over $\Omega$, we write

$\int_\Omega-u_{xx}v = \int_\Omega-f(x)v(x)$.

Then, integrating the left hand side of this equation by parts gives

$-u_{x}v|^1_0+\int_\Omega u_xv_x = \int_\Omega-f(x)v(x)$

Then, since $v(1)=v(0)= 0$, we arrive at

$\int_\Omega u_xv_x = \int_\Omega-f(x)v(x)$

My questions are:

(1) Here, we have that $\Omega$ is an open interval (0,1). How can one integrate over an open interval or in general over an open set? When I studied Riemann integral in real analysis, I always had a function well defined on a closed bounded interval.
What troubles me is that $f(x)$ is defined only "in" $\Omega$, so I do not even know the definition of f(1) and f(0). Similarily, I know that $u_xx$ is in $C^2$, but I do know that wheter $u_xx$ is defined at x = 0 and x = 1.

(2) Again, when doing integration by parts, I do know know whether $v_x$ and $u_x$ are defined "AT" x= 0 and x =1, so how can one integrate $v_xu_x$ from x = 0 to 1?

(3) When evaluating the term $-u_{x}v|^1_0$, I used the fact that $v(0)=v(1)=0$, but what about $u_x(0)$ and $u_x(1)$? Pardon me repeating myself many times, but I do know know whether $u_x(0)$ and $u_x(1)$? are defined.

I have had these questions for such a long time since I first encountered the above weak formulation, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The integration over such an open interval is defined by taking the limits for the approaches to the boundary.   (Since the boundary itself has zero measure what happens there is irrelevant *as long as* the limits do exist.)

$$\int_{(0,1)} f(x)\operatorname d x = \lim_{0<h\to 0}\;\lim_{1>k\to 1}\;\int_h^k f(x)\operatorname d x$$

You don't need to know what anything is *at* the bounds, just what limits are on the approachs from within the interval; which hopefully exist.